# Problem inserting into table from trace file consumes all space in tempdb

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm working with SQL Server 2008 SP3 Enterprise Edition (64-bit)

I'm trying to import a trace file of about 3.5 MB (4667 rows) into a table as following:

```
INSERT INTO DBTRACE with (rowlock)
SELECT * FROM ::fn_trace_gettable('D:\DBTRACES\TRACE.trc', DEFAULT)
```

It keeps executing until it fills up the tempdb (2 data files of 30 GB each) then the following error comes:

> Could not allocate space for object '' in database 'tempdb' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 1105). The step failed.

I already restarted the service and keeps doing it, yesterday it was running fine.

I imported the same trace file into another table in another server and it works successfully and took about 1 second.

Have anyone ever dealt with something like that? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you sure that is the only process that your are running.. Can you try the import in "single mode" ? .. In what DB do you try the trace File.. Try with a new DB

Comment: What database is the `DBTRACE` being created in? Use `DBCC OPENTRAN()` or `sys.dm_tran_database_transactions` to see what is using tempdb.

Comment: Just to see if you get a different result, open the trace with SQL Profiler and use its "Save As > Trace Table ..." option from the file menu.  How does that behave?